# Why is TypeScript allowing an invalid type to be injected?

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection

I have the following dependency being injected:

```
abstract class Person {
    age(): void {};
}

class YoungPerson implements Person {
    age(): void {
        console.log('I am 12');
    }
}

class OlderPerson implements Person {
    age(): void {
        console.log('I am 30');
    }
}

class Man {
    base: Person

    constructor({ base = new YoungPerson() }: { base?: Person } = {}) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    age(): void {
        this.base.age();
    }
}


const man1 = new Man();

man1.age(); // I am 12

const man2 = new Man({ base: new OlderPerson() });

man2.age(); // I am 30
```

The above works fine.

However, this also works...

```
class Car {
    age() {
        console.log('Should not be allowed, but it works.')
    }
}

const man3 = new Man({ base: new Car() });

man3.age(); // Should not be allowed, but it works.
```

Why is typescript allowing me to pass in a `Car` object when the `base` attribute in the `Man` class and the `base` constructor param are defined as type `Person`?

Comment: Because TypeScript is structurally typed, not nominally typed - see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-oop.html#erased-structural-types for more

Comment: Why is `man3.age()` the line you expect to fail? Assuming a `Man` is successfully created, it has an `age`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I assume it would fail because a `type` (in my experience outside of TS) is an actual thing. Not just an implementation of a class.

Comment: I don't see what distinction you're trying to draw, possibly you're describing nominal typing, but I meant why don't you expect the *creation* of `man3` to fail?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeah, exactly. I did expect it to fail. I understand now that TS is more flexible than I imagined at first.

Comment: @jonrsharpe seems the docs realize this comes as a surprise: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-oop.html#identical-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As TypeScript is concerned Car is a Person because it acts as a person (has the age method with the correct signature). TypeScript does not care if you declared that it explicitly implements some type or not.

Comment: So typescript is not strongly typed? I keep reading that it is. Ex: https://www.infoworld.com/article/3538428/what-is-typescript-strongly-typed-javascript.html

Comment: It _is_ strongly typed, it just cares about *shapes* not *identities*.

Comment: "One of TypeScript’s core principles is that type checking focuses on the shape that values have. This is sometimes called “duck typing” or “structural subtyping”. In TypeScript, interfaces fill the role of naming these types, and are a powerful way of defining contracts within your code as well as contracts with code outside of your project." https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Comment: Did not know this. So it offers some duck typing. Thanks for the help.